# Trying to make sense of a proof about metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

**Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $K\subseteq X$ a compact subset, and $E\subseteq X$ a closed subset, such that $K\cap E=\emptyset$. Show that there is some $D>0$ such that $d(x,y)\geq D$ for all $x\in K$ and $y\in E$.

I will break the proof down into segments and place questions where I am not understanding things.

> *Proof.* Suppose otherwise. Then for $D>0$ we claim $d(x,y)\leq D$ for some $x\in K$ and some $y\in E$. Then there are points $x_n \in K$ and $y_n\in E$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\leq1/n$.

I am not entirely sure why we've chosen $x_n$ and $y_n$, is it having to do with the compactness of $K$ and the fact that $E$ is closed?

> Now, define some set $S=\{x_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $S$ is the set of all $x_n's$. We will consider the two cases where either $S$ is infinite or $S$ is finite.

> Case 1: $S$ is finite. This means there is a finite collection of points $\{z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_M\}$ such that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $j\leq M$ such that $x_i=z_j$. Now define the set $N_j\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ with $i\leq j\leq M$ such that $N_j=\{i\in\mathbb{N}|x_i=z_j\}$. By assumption, this means that $\mathbb{N}$ is the union of the $N_j's$. But since there are only finitely many $N_j's$ at least one of them must be infinite.

Why must at least one be infinite? Because $\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite set and the union of the $N_j's$?

> So pick $j$ such that $N_j$ is infinite. We claim that $z_j$ is a limit point of $E$. So we must have $z_j \in E$, a contradiction to the assumption.

The proof does not go into detail here and I'm left trying to figure out how I can prove this claim. Any suggestions?

I am pretty sure I understand the infinite case. There are not any gaps like the finite case. Your pointers and suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

1. We choose $x_n$ and $y_n$ that way because that's convenient for what we will do next.
2. Yes, that is correct.
3. There a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of natural numbers such that $(\forall k\in\Bbb N):x_{n_k}=z_j$. But then $d(z_j,y_{n_k})=d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})\leqslant\frac1{n_k}$. Besides, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{n_k}=0$. So, $\lim_{k\to\infty}d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})=0$; in other words, $\lim_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k}=z_j$. So, and since reach $y_n$ belongs to $E$, $z_j$ is a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ and $E$ are not separated by a minimum distance, then you can find a sequence of pairs of points which are getting arbitrarily close. Since the $x_n$ are in $K$, they have an accumulation point. You should look at that accumulation point for your contradiction.